# How to delete and update data in json format using read and write property of Node.js in angular2 application

Tags: json, angular

I have a json file in `assets/json/abc.json`

I have a requirement that I need to read /abc.json File from assets folder and write some data or delete some data from that /abc.json file according to an input value from a form in html.

I have tried but its not working.
Here, read/write/delete .json file is according to an input from user through a click event.

### abc.json

```
[
    {
        "imgPath": "fa-users",
        "dashboardName": "Command Center",
        "urlToVisit": "dashboards/static/commandcenter"
    },
    {
        "imgPath": "fa-tachometer",
        "dashboardName": "HP Dashboard",
        "urlToVisit": "dashboards/static/hpdash"
    },
    {
        "imgPath": "fa-cube",
        "dashboardName": "HP APJ",
        "urlToVisit": "dashboards/static/hpapj"
    }
]
```

### abc.component.html

```
<form class="rmpm" (submit)="AddNewDashboardBox($event)">
    <div class="form-group rmpm">
        <div class='col-xs-12 rmpm'>
            Enter Dashboard Name
            <br>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control rmpm" placeholder="Dashboard Name" name="dashboardName"
                required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-12 rmpm'>
            Enter Icon Name
            <br>
            <input type="text"class="form-control rmpm" placeholder="Icon Name" name="IconName"
                required>
            <br>
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-12 rmpm'>
            Enter Url Path to Visit
            <br>
            <input type="text"  class="form-control rmpm" placeholder="Url Path" name="UrlPath"
                required>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
</form>
```

### abc.component.ts

```
 AddNewDashboardBox(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let dashboardNameInput = e.target.elements[0].value;
    let IconNameInput = e.target.elements[1].value;
    let UrlPathInput = e.target.elements[2].value;

    var obj = {
      table: []
    };

    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    var fs = require('fs');

    fs.readFile('assets/json/abc.json', 'utf8', function readFileCallback(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        obj = JSON.parse(data); //now it an object
        obj.table.push({ "imgPath": IconNameInput , "dashboardName": dashboardNameInput, "urlToVisit": UrlPathInput }); //add some data
        json = JSON.stringify(obj); //convert it back to json
        fs.writeFile('assets/json/abc.json', json, 'utf8'); 
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular application is running on client browser and the file you want to change is residing on server. So this thing is not possible.

You will have to write an api to which angular will make rest call with new data and then that server will make the required changes in file on file (that is on server).

I recommend you to see the client server architecture for in depth details.

Comment: The file is local... residing in assets/json

Comment: when you run application the file gets served over http i.e. not accessed via file system.

Comment: Can you show, how to write an api to which angular will make rest call with new data.

Comment: for that you need to write api in node or in any server. And as mentioned in your question I guess you know how to write same in node. There is no angular code running on server side